# Add a class to an element in parent page based on iframe content

Tags: javascript, html, class, iframe

I have a page with a number of anchors that act as buttons to load content into an iframe on the page.  If content is loaded into the iframe from outside the parent I would like to add a class to the relevant anchor on the parent page to show what content is being displayed in the iframe.

Parent page is something like this:

```
<head>
<base target="iframe">
</head>
<body>
<a class="btn" href="dog.html">
<a class="btn" href="cat.html">
<a class="btn" href="bird.html">
<iframe src="blank.html" id="iframe" name="iframe"></iframe>
</body>
```

When one of the child pages is loaded into the iframe I would like the anchor to highlight based on what content is loaded, like this:

```
<a class="btn selected" href="dog.html">
```

How can I do this?  I'm a novice at javascript but I believe it can be done, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you "loading" the iframe from the anchors?

Comment: @gforce301 loading a page into the iframe from an anchor is done with the code above.  Loading a page into the iframe from outside the parent page is done with some javascript on both the parent and child pages that will force any of the child pages to always display inside a specific iframe